# PL/SQL Cursor using inventory and transaction tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

The question is : Process the transactions and determine the impact on inventory. Display information that gives the original inventory and the inventory after the sales, returns and purchases have been processed, using cursors.

**My two tables are:**

**Table one is itemid, itemname, and quanity.**

```
ITEM ITEMNAME                     QUANITY
---- ------------------------- ----------
1111 Computer                          50
2222 TV                                10
3333 Camera                            35
4444 Phone                             40
```

**AND**

**Table two is itemid, itemname, code(s = sale, r = return, p = purchases), and itemsmoved(referring to the code..example 1111 sold 2)**

```
ITEM ITEMNAME                  C ITEMSMOVED
---- ------------------------- - ----------
1111 Computer                  S          2
2222 TV                        S          5
3333 Camera                    S         15
4444 Phone                     S          7
1111 Computer                  P         10
2222 TV                        R          2
3333 Camera                    P         20
4444 Phone                     R          3
```

**I also created a table to insert into:**

```
SQL> create table updatedinv
  2  (itemid varchar2(4),
  3  itemname varchar2(15),
  4  orginv number(4),
  5  updatedinv number(4));
```

My PL/SQL code is:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  v_idno      inventory.itemid%TYPE;
  v_name      inventory.itemname%TYPE;
  v_quantity  inventory.quanity%TYPE;
  v_tidno     transaction.itemid%TYPE;
  v_code      transaction.code%TYPE;
  v_move      transaction.itemsmoved%TYPE;
  v_updated   updatedinv.updatedinv%TYPE;
  CURSOR inventory_cursor IS
     SELECT itemid, itemname, quanity FROM inventory
     ORDER BY itemid;
  CURSOR transaction_cursor IS
     SELECT itemid, code, itemsmoved FROM transaction
     WHERE v_idno = itemid
     ORDER BY itemid;
  BEGIN
     OPEN inventory_cursor;
     LOOP
       FETCH inventory_cursor INTO v_idno, v_name, v_quantity;
       EXIT WHEN inventory_cursor%NOTFOUND;
       IF transaction_cursor%ISOPEN THEN
         CLOSE transaction_cursor;
       END IF;
       OPEN transaction_cursor;
       v_updated := 0;
       LOOP
         FETCH transaction_cursor INTO v_tidno, v_code, v_move;
         EXIT WHEN transaction_cursor%NOTFOUND;
         IF v_code = 'S' THEN
         v_updated := v_quantity - v_move;
         END IF;
         IF v_code = 'R' THEN
         v_updated := v_quantity + v_move;
         END IF;
         IF v_code = 'P' THEN
         v_updated := v_quantity + v_move;
         END IF;
                END LOOP;
       INSERT into updatedinv 
          VALUES(v_idno, v_name, v_quantity, v_updated);
       CLOSE transaction_cursor;
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE inventory_cursor;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

**It is calculating code P and R but not S, the sales are not getting minused before the purchases or returns:**

```
SQL> @ loop1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select *
  2  from updatedinv;

ITEM ITEMNAME            ORGINV UPDATEDINV
---- --------------- ---------- ----------
1111 Computer                50         60
2222 TV                      10         12
3333 Camera                  35         55
4444 Phone                   40         43
```

**The results should look like this:**

```
SQL> select *
  2  from updatedinv;

ITEM ITEMNAME            ORGINV UPDATEDINV
---- --------------- ---------- ----------
1111 Computer                50         58
2222 TV                      10          7
3333 Camera                  35         40
4444 Phone                   40         36
```

Comment: Please, show some result data from your sample data, it is not clear enough what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: i am trying to take table two to update table one with cursors

Comment: @JorgeCampos i updated with code

Comment: @JorgeCampos it should subtract all the sales than updated the total with returns and purchases

Answer (score 1):

You have written in way complicated fashion. You can use implicit cursors for this purpose and avoid lot of coding.

```
DECLARE
   l_updatedinv updatedinv.updatedinv%type;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (select * from inventory order by itemid)
   LOOP
       l_updatedinv := i.quanity;
       FOR j IN (select * from transaction where itemid = i.itemid)
       LOOP
       l_updatedinv := 
           case when j.code = 'S' then l_updatedinv - j.itemsmoved
           when j.code in ('P', 'R') then l_updatedinv + j.itemsmoved
           end;
      END LOOP;
   INSERT into updatedinv 
      VALUES(i.itemid, i.itemname, i.quanity, l_updatedinv);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi If I understand you question correctly the issue with your code is in this line

```
v_updated := v_quantity - v_move;
```

Each time you go through the loop you add / subtract from v_quantity (that never changes) so it will only effectively process the last transaction.

See amended loop below by setting v_updated equal to v_quantity before the loop and then using only v_updated for your calculations during the loop you should get accurate results.

```
 OPEN inventory_cursor;
 LOOP
   FETCH inventory_cursor INTO v_idno, v_name, v_quantity;
   EXIT WHEN inventory_cursor%NOTFOUND;
   IF transaction_cursor%ISOPEN THEN
     CLOSE transaction_cursor;
   END IF;
   v_updated := v_quantity; -- Added line
   OPEN transaction_cursor;
   v_updated := 0;
   LOOP
     FETCH transaction_cursor INTO v_tidno, v_code, v_move;
     EXIT WHEN transaction_cursor%NOTFOUND;
     IF v_code = 'S' THEN
     v_updated := v_updated - v_move; -- changed v_quantity to v_updated
     END IF;
     IF v_code = 'R' THEN
     v_updated := v_updated  + v_move; -- changed v_quantity to v_updated
     END IF;
     IF v_code = 'P' THEN
     v_updated := v_updated + v_move; -- changed v_quantity to v_updated
     END IF;
            END LOOP;
   INSERT into updatedinv 
      VALUES(v_idno, v_name, v_quantity, v_updated);
   CLOSE transaction_cursor;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE inventory_cursor;
```

Comment: how owuld that subtract or add my starting quantity since, its not pulling from v_quantity

Comment: i just implemented that and it didnt work since it is not pulling from the original quantity

Comment: @JeffMercier I set the v_updated = v_quantity before the loop so that we are working with a consistent value (v_updated := v_quantity; -- Added line) If you added v_quantity to the 'S' Condition you are assuming that 'S' will always be processed first.  It may be the case but is not a wise Idea to assume... And also that there will only ever be one 'S' transaction.